# Draw text outside of CGRect.

Tags: ios, frame, cgrect

I am using Apple's Sample Code TheElements for this question. How would I go about drawing text outside of the elementSymbolRectangle. For example I would like to display the Elements Name, but I need it to be outside of the elementSymbolRectangle. I am new to programming and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

```
 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

        if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
            [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
            [self setupUserInterface];

            // set the background color of the view to clearn
            self.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)jumpToWikipedia:(id)sender {

        // create the string that points to the correct Wikipedia page for the element name
        NSString *wikiPageString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@", self.element.name];
        if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:wikiPageString]])
        {
            // there was an error trying to open the URL. for the moment we'll simply ignore it.
        }
    }

    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        // get the background image for the state of the element
        // position it appropriately and draw the image
        //
        UIImage *backgroundImage = [self.element stateImageForAtomicElementView];
        CGRect elementSymbolRectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, [backgroundImage size].width, [backgroundImage size].height);
        [backgroundImage drawInRect:elementSymbolRectangle];

        // all the text is drawn in white
        [[UIColor whiteColor] set];

        // draw the element number
        UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:32];
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(10,5);
        [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.element.atomicNumber] drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];

        // draw the element symbol
        CGSize stringSize = [self.element.symbol sizeWithFont:font];
        point = CGPointMake((self.bounds.size.width-stringSize.width-10),5);
        [self.element.symbol drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];
```

Comment: My suggestion would be that you get the points where you make your element symbol drawing then create a UILabel at the bottom of the symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem.

```
UILabel *scoreLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.bounds.size.width / 2), -50.0, 100.0, 100.0) ];
scoreLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter;
scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];
[self addSubview:scoreLabel];
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Test"];
```